# Wired Connection Problem on a Lenovo Workstation e20

Tags: 12.04, networking

After upgrading to 12.04 my interent connection no longer works. More precisely it is really, really, slow, and occasionally will connect, but do so only for a few moments and then disappear again. I am on a Lenovo Workstation e20.

Output of ifconfig:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f3:95:00:64:3e  
           inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::72f3:95ff:fe00:643e/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:7398 errors:0 dropped:74 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:6684 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:5407828 (5.4 MB)  TX bytes:854343 (854.3 KB)
           Interrupt:20 Memory:fb120000-fb140000 

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
           RX packets:1587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:1587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:152089 (152.0 KB)  TX bytes:152089 (152.0 KB)
```

I am really at a loss for what to do. I am relatively new to Ubuntu, searched the other user questions and couldn't figure this out.

Comment: I had this problem not to long ago... turned out it was the network cable... Not sure how or why... but maybe something you might want to consider looking into...

Comment: Not a cable problem, checked the hardware. Laptop works fine when connected to the cable.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to throw that out there...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: It is a Lenovo e20 Workstation. When I get home I'll run the terminal commands to get the required info and update. In the meantime I know it is using the e1000e driver (as I started to looking into that to see if that was the problem).

Comment: Running lspci I get: Ethernet Controller: Intel Corporation 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)

Comment: Okay so for what it is worth, the problem seems to be related to the internal ethernet card. I have hooked up a usb wireless card and don't seem to be having any problems.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading to 12.04 LTS.

The following solution worked for me.

Open this file in a text editor as root:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

(One way to do that is `gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces`.)

Add these lines to the file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save the file and quit the text editor.

Now restart the network:

- [How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and then enter this in the command prompt :

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

After that, retry connecting

. It should connect then.... :)

Answer (score 0):

To restart the network interfaces:

```
ifconfig (network interface) down && ifconfig (network interface) up
```

where `(network interface)` is the network interface id - `eth0` or `wlan0`.